# Copy & Paste issue in PowerPoint and Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint, word-2016

since one ore two weeks we have a problem by using very simple VBA Paste-Codes in PowerPoint and Word. This codes we use for a few years without changes. Maybe it is an "Update-Bug" after a MS Office Update?

First **PowerPoint**: Although our codes are a bit more complex, you can reproduce the error just with these two lines:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).copy
ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste Index:=5
```

The procedure stops in the Paste-Line with:

> "Slides (unknown member): Invalid request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here."

Although it doesn´t run by itself I can resume the procedure with F8 or F5 without error.

A similar issue we have in **Word** by using **Selection.Range.Paste**. I can also debug/resume with F8 or F5, but first I get the error

> "Laufzeitfehler '4605': Dieser Befehl ist nicht verfügbar." (so
> command not available).

Both issues came up in the last two weeks my colleagues say (I was in vacation, so I cannot determine the exact day), after running perfect for a few years.

Win10Pro 64Bit
Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise

Thank you very much in advance for your time and your help.

Tom

Comment: If the code can be resumed and completes its operations it suggests that it may simply a case of the OS needing time to catch up. Try adding `DoEvents` before the paste.

Comment: Hi Timothy, DoEvents before the paste solves the problem :-) Great, thank you very much!